# Jquery ui doesn't revert after mouse/touch release

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, angular-material

I want to create slider using Jquery UI and Jquery UI Touch Punch (because with this, dragable items start to work on mobile). Everything works fine in browser, but in mobile device or in Chrome mobile view draggable objects **reverts** not when i release the mouse or touch, but when i release and touch some where not on this object.

Here is my js code

```
var elm = $('#draggable');
            elm.draggable({
                axis: "x",
                containment: "parent",
                revert: true
            });
```

And my slider html

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center ui-widget-content" id="slider" class="slider">
<div id="draggable" style="left:0%; top:0" class="slide-img "></div>
<p>TEXT</p>
<ng-md-icon class="no-margin" icon="arrow_forward"></ng-md-icon>
```

Comment: Please edit and add more details, such as JQuery & jQuery UI versions being used. Is there a reason you are nor adjusting the Slider via CSS and using Draggable instead?

Comment: I created a test fiddle, and nothing appears to work: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/omtg939h/

Comment: It doesn't mater with css or Jquery. The problem is that on device, the release function i happening when i release and click somewhere else.